# How to use SELECT DISTINCT properly?

Tags: mysql, sql

I made query like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT TahunMasuk (SELECT COUNT(LamaStudi) 
FROM studi WHERE LamaStudi < 2) from studi order by TahunMasuk
```

but, the query is error. What may I do to solve that query so that I can count `LamaStudi` based by `TahunMasuk`? The result example is like this

[image]

Here is my table
**studi**

[image]

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query should return the result you want:

```
SELECT TahunMasuk, 
  COUNT(CASE WHEN LamaStudi < 2 THEN 1 END) AS `LamaStudi < 2`,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN LamaStudi BETWEEN 2 AND 2.4 THEN 1 END) AS `LamaStudi < 2-2.4`,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN LamaStudi > 2.4 THEN 1 END) AS `LamaStudi > 2.4`,
FROM studi
GROUP BY TahunMasuk;
```

In your sample data, you have some rows where LamaStudi is NULL, but it's not clear how you want to handle that. If you want NULL to be counted as zero, then you need this small modification:

```
  COUNT(CASE WHEN COALESCE(LamaStudi,0) < 2 THEN 1 END) AS `LamaStudi < 2`,
```

You were using DISTINCT incorrectly. The DISTINCT option applies to all columns in the select-list. 
The following rows are all distinct rows:

```
a b c
a b d
a e d
```

DISTINCT keeps a row in the result if *any* column is different from other rows.

If you want to reduce the result set to rows with distinct values in *one* column, use GROUP BY.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT TahunMasuk, COUNT(*)
FROM studi
GROUP BY TahunMasuk
```

Comment: I want to count "LamaStudi" group by "TahunMasuk". Do you know how to make that query?

Comment: LamaStudi<2, LamaStudi>2, etc

Comment: You can use having count(*)<2 or having count(*)>2 etc